# Is it possible to disable the "Add Exception" button in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ssl

I want to disable/remove the "Add Exception..." button in Firefox to prevent users to accept invalid SSL certificates.

[image: SSL certificate error]

How can I achieve this? Google does not show up any useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's no specific way to do this. But you can disable completely the "Bad Certificate" page, and replace it for an alert box. **This also disable all error pages**. Go to `about:config` and look for the [`browser.xul.error_pages.enabled`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.xul.error_pages.enabled) key, set it to `false`. Now each error page is disable and replaced by an error box.

Another solution to make more difficult to the users, is changing the **Add Exception** behavior, setting the key [`browser.ssl_override_behavior`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.ssl_override_behavior) to `0`. This will not populate the url in the dialog box, nor prefetch the certificate.

Reference:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.xul.error_pages.expert_bad_cert

Comment: Great tip disabling the error page! I was also looking for such feature and the only thing I had found was `browser.ssl_override_behavior`. Do you know a way to disable *permanent* exceptions but allow temporary exceptions?